# Workarounds needed rendering with AMD on Mac with ProRenderer and using Parallels and Virtual Machines to run Blender

Tags: rendering, texturing, image

I have the new MacBook pro 2020 + eGPU Sonett650 + AMD 6700XT and I am using AMD pro render but the 'images as textures' feature wont let me load up my keyed out Green Screen footage to render my video of my characters into a scene that I have built around the same motion tracked footage (just like this oak teaches here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxD6H3ri8RI)

The problem is in AMD ProRenderer I can't load movies or images as textures. So I think a work around is to render the image sequences, shadows and reflections in Cycles and then the rest of the scene in AMD Pro-render. This means I dont need three days of rendering for a 30 second scene hopefully.

I am a contributor to Sheepit Render farm and have loads of points there but they only allow 500mb uploads and 4k image sequences get big quick and I can't seem to work out how to break the project up into small pieces without loosing the video tracking data.

I have also tried to run Virtual Machine and parallels to get Blender running there and then render off of AMD GPUs in Blender there but I can't even get blender working there. Please advise!

I am doing all I can to stay on Mac because I've just brought this computer and I find Windows certainly does not "just work'. Anything we can do to force some pathways open for blender workflows on Mac I am all ears.

Many thanks
Charles

Green Campus Ltd
Create.Green
3D Printing Eco-villages from Sunshine